# SQL Server want to populate Union Data in Separate Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is as shown below:

```
    SELECT a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User FROM Meter a INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub1'
UNION
SELECT a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User FROM Meter a INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub2'
UNION
SELECT a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User FROM Meter a INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub3'
```

The result i am getting is:

[image]

What i am expecting is:

[image]

Request you all to please help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Its actually the Product table

Comment: Can you post test data? Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `union`?

Comment: I was trying to populate the values row wise based on my three sub products. Thats why i did a union.

Comment: Show us the table data as well, the unwanted result doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult without test data, but conditional aggregation is an option:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Viscosity' THEN a.ACTUAL END) AS Viscosity_Actual,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Viscosity' THEN a.Name END) AS Viscosity_Name,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Viscosity' THEN a.User END) AS Viscosity_User,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Pressure' THEN a.ACTUAL END) AS Pressure_Actual,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Pressure' THEN a.Name END) AS Pressure_Name,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Pressure' THEN a.User END) AS Pressure_User,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Temperature' THEN a.ACTUAL END) AS Temperature_Actual,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Temperature' THEN a.Name END) AS Temperature_Name,
   MAX(CASE a.Name = 'Temperature' THEN a.User END) AS Temperature_User
FROM Meter a 
INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID = b.ID 
WHERE 
   (b.ProductName = 'Product1') AND 
   ((b.SUBProduct = 'Sub1') OR (b.SUBProduct = 'Sub2') OR (b.SUBProduct = 'Sub3'))
GROUP BY b.SUBProduct
```

Answer (score 1):

Try joining multiple subqueries:

```sql
SELECT a.ACTUAL AS [Viscosity_Actual], a.Name AS [Viscosity_Name], a.User AS [Viscosity_User],
b.ACTUAL AS [Pressure_Actual], b.Name AS [Pressure_Name], b.User AS [Pressure_User],
c.ACTUAL AS [Temperature_Actual], c.Name AS [Temperature_Name], c.User AS [Temperature_User]
FROM (

   SELECT a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User, b.ProductName
   FROM Meter a
   INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID
   WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub1'

) a
LEFT JOIN (

   SELECT a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User, b.ProductName
   FROM Meter a
   INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID       
   WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub2'

) b
ON a.ProductName = b.ProductName
LEFT JOIN (

   SELECT a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User, b.ProductName
   FROM Meter a
   INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID       
   WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub3'

) c
ON a.ProductName = c.ProductName
```

Note that for this to work reliably, you need to be certain that if there is data in the second or third subquery, then there will also be data in the first subquery (dependent on how the tables are populated).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.ACTUAL,T1.Name,T1.User,T2.ACTUAL,T2.Name,T2.User,T3.ACTUAL,T3.Name,T3.User FROM
(SELECT a.PRODUCT_ID, a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User FROM Meter a INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub1') T1
JOIN
(SELECT a.PRODUCT_ID, a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User FROM Meter a INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub2') T2 on T1.PRODUCT_ID = T2.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN
(SELECT a.PRODUCT_ID, a.ACTUAL, a.Name, b.User FROM Meter a INNER JOIN Product b ON a.PRODUCT_ID=b.ID WHERE b.ProductName='Product1' and b.SUBProduct='Sub3') T3 on T2.PRODUCT_ID = T3.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try out the solution :)